# Layout for a custom dialog box

Tags: qt

In my Qt desktop app i need a dialog for a user to enter some data.  So I select: New file | Qt | Designer form class then Dialog with buttons bottom and name it appropriately.

In the new dialog's constructor I create some labels and line edits and add them to a grid layout.  Like this:

```
ui->setupUi(this);

partNoLabel = new QLabel(tr("&Part No:"));
partDescLabel = new QLabel(tr("&Description:"));

partNoLineEdit = new QLineEdit();
partDescLineEdit = new QLineEdit();

partNoLabel->setBuddy(partNoLineEdit);
partDescLabel->setBuddy(partDescLineEdit);

supplierLabel = new QLabel(tr("Supplier"));
supPartNoLabel = new QLabel(tr("Part No"));
supplierLineEdit = new QLineEdit();
supPartNoLineEdit = new QLineEdit();

supplierLabel->setBuddy(supplierLineEdit);
supPartNoLabel->setBuddy(supPartNoLineEdit);


QGridLayout *dlgLayout = new QGridLayout;
dlgLayout->addWidget(partNoLabel, 0, 0);
dlgLayout->addWidget(partNoLineEdit, 0, 1);
dlgLayout->addWidget(partDescLabel, 1, 0);
dlgLayout->addWidget(partDescLineEdit, 1, 1);

dlgLayout->addWidget(supplierLabel, 2, 0);
dlgLayout->addWidget(supplierLineEdit, 2, 1);
dlgLayout->addWidget(supPartNoLabel, 3, 0);
dlgLayout->addWidget(supPartNoLineEdit, 3, 1);

setLayout(dlgLayout);

setWindowTitle("New part");
```

When displayed, though - it looks terrible:

[image: dialog showing buttons over edit boxes]

and when resized, looks worse:

[image: resized dialog showing buttons over edit boxes]

This is obviously unacceptable, how do I fix this, or how should I have done this?

Fixed version :

I followed Gábor Angyal advice and did it manually, removing and adding a button box in code.  I also changed to using a FormLayout as described in this article: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq25-formlayout.html

The resulting form looks like:

[image: fixed dialog]

which still needs a tweak or two, but at least the buttons are in the right place :D .

Comment: You need to find layout that holds your buttons (ok/cancel) and compose new vertical box layout that will contain your grid layout and buttons layout.

Comment: Thank you - Is it best not to use "button at bottom" option in the dialog set-up wizard at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you created a layout manually, but did nat add the button box to it. I suggest you to either create the whole form using the designer, or do everything manually, but do not mix the two.

**With designer**

- Open the .ui file in the designer.
- With right-click set a grid layout.
- Drag&Drop the texboxes.

**Manual**

- Remove the button box in the designer.
- Check out: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialogbuttonbox.html
- Create and add the dialog box manually to your layout.